# How to put HTML elements in a line?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, text-align

I've got this code...

```
        <div class="header">
            <div class="mainh">

                <div class="table">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>          
        </div>
```

And what I want is to put the `ul`, `li` and `a` in a single line with the same distance between them.
How do I make it?
BTW I tried something. What I tried:

```
div.table ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

...but it doesn't change the alignment.

Comment: Try: li { display: inline; }

Comment: Don't work as well. By the way, I have already got an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul li 
{
   float: left; /* To make it in a single line */
   margin-right: 50px; /* Distance */
   margin-left: 50px; /* Distance */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
ul li { float: left; margin-right:30px; }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="mainh">
    <div class="table">
      <ul>
        <li><a>smth</a></li>
        <li><a>smth</a></li>
        <li><a>smth</a></li>
        <li><a>smth</a></li>
        <li><a>smth</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Going to accept your answer in 12 minutes (when I will be able to)

Answer (score 1):

```css
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
        <div class="header">
            <div class="mainh">

                <div class="table">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>          
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your display to inline instead of block. block would make it list in multiple lines. Inline would make it look like a header menu in one line

Comment: No, that isn't what I needed

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```css
.ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: It puts everything to the middle, but not in a single line